# Two split view controllers in a tab bar controller causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

My app requires  two separate split view controllers. First I created first split view controller that works fine , now added second split view controller but second split view controller causes crash.

[image]

in first split's master:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) WODTutorialDetailsView *wods;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //init detail instance
    self.wods=  (WODTutorialDetailsView *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    [self populateTableview];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"WODs";
}
```

in second split's master:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) LogDetailViewController *wods;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //init detail instance
    self.wods=  (LogDetailViewController *)[[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject] topViewController];
    [self populateTableview];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"WODs";
}
```

Error I get is:

```
-[LogDetailViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x229c4f40
2013-02-01 15:12:10.625 WOD Log[2473:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[LogDetailViewController topViewController]:
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: You might get this to work, but Apple says that a UISplitViewController has to be the root view controller of the window.

Comment: that doesnt make any sense to me , screen size on ipad is huge I dont want whole view to show only a tableview then push a detail view every time on didselect

Comment: Well, apparently it did make sense to Apple.

Comment: Why dont you try to create your own SplitViewController. I suppose containment api are so powerful that you can create even a view controller of 10 by 10 view and then implement a tableview controller upon it.

Comment: Apple say you have to use UISplitViewController at the top of your UI. Right or wrong, it's what they've specified, and if you ignore it, all hell can break loose. You'll have better luck using a 3rd party split view controller reimplementation.

Comment: 3rd party split view examples are very old and some of them are very confusing, should I add a tableview and uiviewcontroller as subviews to a uiviewcontroller to imitate split view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never heard of a good rational for this but Apple does say that a UISplitViewController should be the topmost UI Controller. Although this project is a bit old, its description is pretty clear in what it does:

> Custom UISplitView which can be used with navigation based project.

Take a look:
https://github.com/palaniraja/cUISplitViewController